# Refactor [style.visibility]="" logic into function

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have this multiselect in an html template:

find-form.component.html

```
<div class="row has-error-text">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xl-4 offset-xl-4 input-group btn-group" style="height:64px;">
        <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
            <multiselect #multiselect></multiselect>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row error-text" [style.visibility]="multiselect.selectedCategories.length < 1 && submitted ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xl-4 offset-xl-4">
        <small class="text-danger">Please select at least 1 category.</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I change this:

```
<div class="row error-text" [style.visibility]="multiselect.selectedCategories.length < 1 && submitted ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
```

into this:

```
<div class="row error-text" [style.visibility]="multiselect.getVisibility()">
```

Then have this function in find-form.component.ts:

```
  getVisibility() {
    if (this.multiselect.selectedCategories.length < 1 && this.submitted) {
      return 'visible'
    } else {
      return 'hidden'
    }
  }
```

It would be more unit testable and also easier to debug and understand.

It causes me to get the error:

> "multiselect is not defined"

The thing is my find-form.component.ts doesnt have a this.multiselect.  But in its template it has `<multiselect #multiselect></multiselect>` so does that mean it does actually have this.multiselect? Or if not, how do I pass it the instance of the multiselect?

How do I put the style.visibility into a function like I attempted to do, without getting the "multiselect is not defined" error?

Comment: what you have defined for `multiselect` in your component ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9 Just attempting it with `@ViewChild('multiselct') multiselect;` in the component but I don't think it's working

Comment: `Viewchild` get set in `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook and before that you are trying to bind multiselect in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just be able to do this:

TS:

```
getVisibility(multiselect) {
    if (multiselect.selectedCategories.length < 1 && this.submitted) return 'visible'
    else return 'hidden'
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row error-text" [style.visibility]="getVisibility(multiselect)">
```

Answer (score 0):

what else you can do is,

```
<div class="row error-text" [hidden]="getVisibility()">

getVisibility() {
    if (this.multiselect.selectedCategories.length < 1 && this.submitted) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`@ViewChild` is correct way but you are calling `getVisibility` function with `multiselect.getVisibility()` which is not correct way as `getVisibility` function is in component and you have to use it directly so change your html as below:

```
<div class="row error-text" [style.visibility]="getVisibility()">
```